# Selecting each records from drop-down & clicking on Search button in selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium

Select each record in drop-down lists and click on submit button and results are displayed then again select next value in drop-down list & click submit in selenium

```
int i=1;
java.util.List<WebElement> portddl=(java.util.List<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.id("selectOption"));

for(WebElement selectOption : portddl){
    if(selectOption.getText() != null ) 
    {
        selectOption.click();
        //Select se=new Select((WebElement) portddl);
        //se.selectByIndex(2);

        WebElement click1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='buttonSSL']"));
        click1.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        break;
    }

    else {
        se.selectByIndex(i);
        selectOption.click();

        WebElement click1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='buttonSSL']"));
        click1.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
i++;
```

Comment: Your requirement is confusing, try creating a jsfiddle

Comment: In search page, I have drop-down lists of port no  & search button, need to select each port no &  click on search button to view the record against each port no. How to automate in Selenium web-driver.